# Unable to list Users in a view using MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to list all users in a view but with no success. There are loads of questions here referring to the same problem and I have tried most of the replies, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. The following is the simplest implementation I could come up with but the error message is the same whatever method I use.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
}
<ul>
  @foreach (var user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
  {
    <li>Name: @user.UserName </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `MembershipUser` instead of `var`.

```
@foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
    <li>Name: @user.UserName</li>
}
```

This being said I hope you realize that this is a total anti-MVC pattern. It's not the views responsibility to pull/fetch data from some stores. They should only use data that it is being passed to them from a controller action under the form of a strongly typed view model.

So here's the correct way to do this.

As always you start by defining a view model which will contain the data that you need to show in your view (in this case a list of usernames):

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = Membership
        .GetAllUsers()
        .Cast<MembershipUser>()
        .Select(x => new UserViewModel
        {
            Name = x.UserName
        });
    return View(model);
}
```

then a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserViewModel>
<ul>
    @Html.DisplayForModel()
</ul>
```

and a display template for a given user which will be rendered for each item of the model collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/UserViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model UserViewModel
<li>Name: @Model.Name</li>
```

Comment: Brilliant ! - Thanks Darin. It finally works.
I appreciate your advice. My example was the the simplest I could find to demonstrate the problem.
I will now change things to follow your recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry to revive this post but I have been trying to get this to work for ages and I get this error everytime, I am using MVC2 if that makes a difference: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.UserViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNameSpace.UserViewModel'